# Honda Accord 2.0L i-VTEC Executive 4door - Automatic Transmission

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

I'm planning to buy a Honda Accord 2.0L i-VTEC. Can someone tell me which drive modes (if any) the automatic transmission has? Does it have a manual mode like the Nissan 350GT/Infiniti G35?

Comment: To whomever voted to close this as off-topic, I'd suggest the OP is asking about the operation of the transmission, not purchasing advice. They want to know if the automatic transmission compares in operation to the Nissan 350GT.

Comment: Which model year?

Comment: @tlhIngan 2006 Executive